# Function pointers - pass arguments to a function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have a problem with the code that uses function pointers, take a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*VFUNCV)(void);

void fun1(int a, double b) { printf("%d %f fun1\n", a, b); }
void fun2(int a, double b) { printf("%d %f fun2\n", a, b); }

void call(int which, VFUNCV* fun, int a, double b)
{
    fun[which](a, b);
}

int main()
{
    VFUNCV fun[2] = {fun1, fun2};
    call(0, fun, 3, 4.5);
    return 0;
}
```

And it produces errors:

```
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c||In function ‘call’:|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c|11|error: too many arguments to function ‘*(fun + (unsigned int)((unsigned int)which * 4u))’|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c||In function ‘main’:|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c|16|warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c|16|warning: (near initialization for ‘fun[0]’) [enabled by default]|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c|16|warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|
/home/ivy/Desktop/CTests//funargs.c|16|warning: (near initialization for ‘fun[1]’) [enabled by default]|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 4 warnings ===|
```

I used a Code::Blocks to compile it.

Its simple, when I dont have any arguments but with some, I got confused:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void (*VFUNCV)(void);

void fun1() { printf("fun1\n"); }
void fun2() { printf("fun2\n"); }

void call(int which, VFUNCV* fun)
{
    fun[which]();
}

int main()
{
    VFUNCV fun[2] = {fun1, fun2};
    call(1, fun);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your function pointer does not fit to your function declarations.
Try defining it as

```
typedef void (*VFUNCV)(int, double);
```

Answer (score 6):

Fix `typedef` to

```
typedef void (*VFUNCV)(int , double );
```

as `fun1` and `fun2` accepts two argument of type `int` and `double`